# VB.Net: Detect Webcam

Tags: vb.net, webcam, detection

How can I programmatically detect whether a webcam device is plugged in to the PC or not, return 'True' or 'False.

Answer (score 0):

Might be some better way of doing this but the only one I can think of would be to use `GetRawInputDeviceList` to enumerate all USB devices and then using `GetRawInputDeviceInfo` to get out more information about them.
Webcams should show up as HID, but I don't know if there's any way to tell for sure if it's a webcam.

See [here](http://www.pinvoke.net/default.aspx/user32.getrawinputdevicelist) for a C# sample (could probably use a C# to VB.Net converter if you're not comfortable with C#).