# Access web cam using vb.net

Tags: .net, vb.net, video-streaming

few days earlier I've came to a problem where I have to access the default web cam, Actually I was making an vb.net app (desktop based) where an user can directly do video chat with the other user via Online or Offline(lan based), the type of web cam can be anything, like web cams installed in modern laptops, or external web cam. I don't know anything about how to acces web cam from vb.net, how capture video & then transmit it to the other user. Please help me.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2946180/vb-net-detect-webcam

Answer (score 2):

try to follow this example

http://www.codeproject.com/KB/audio-video/WebcamUsingDirectShowNET.aspx

and this thread.

[Access webcam and microphone input in VB.net](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1451627/access-webcam-and-microphone-input-in-vb-net)

Regards.